# How I can delete App's ID from the apple developer center?

Tags: ios

I can't delete my old App's ID's from the apple developer center?
Why?
I can't find a delete button or something else.
Anybody know where I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Select the app id, click on edit, scroll down and click delete